# Issues with Delve user profiles and getting data using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm detecting a couple of issues with the Delve Profile and Microsoft Graph API.

Issue 1:
Users can't update the Work Phone via the Delve interface, only Admins can via the Admin Panel.

Issue 2:
Via Graph, I can only retrieve Work Phone and Mobile Phone from some users. The pattern I am seeing is, that I can get the properties for old users (they were migrated from a local AD). But, newer users (some with 4-year-old accounts) which have had the Mobile Phone property filled for a long time, are returning null values.

I have tested this on multiple, isolated tenants. On a different tenant, which has the Work Phone property filled for all users, is always returning empty values for the businessPhones property via Graph.

I have tested this via the Graph Explorer interface, Graph .Net SDK and manual ReST requests, always with the same results.

Further  tests we made:

Compared 3 users on UPS which have the Mobile Phone and the Work Phone properties filled.

I run Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "user" | select *, with the following results:

User 1: returns WorkPhone and MobilePhone.
User 2: returns WorkPhone. MobilePhone is empty.
User 3: WorkPhone and MobilePhone are empty.

When the value returns via PowerShell, graph returns it too.

Thanks
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to get the user's profile.

Based on my test, we can use the endpoint `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}` to get the user's office phone(but not the work phone) and the mobile phone.

The below is my test result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed up with the Users API product manager. We partially reverted the security fix that was causing this issue. The security fix was done because an app with user write capabilities could update an admin’s user properties (telephone, mobilePhone and otherMails) that are used by Self-service password reset (SSPR) system.  A user could then use SSPR to verify as that admin, and reset that admins password.

These properties can again be updated for any user except users in more privileged roles.  Basically we need to ensure that no elevation of privilege paths exist. There’s an update pending to the docs.
We have an active review in progress on a new permission (app only and app+user) that allows ALL users to have these properties update-able. No ETA currently on this being released.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy for the feedback.